# Get next object id which isn't disabled

Tags: javascript, object

The current problem now is i changed the function i got from the awnser but the previous one doesn't work.

```
function getPrev(currPhotoId) {
    var i = currPhotoId - 1;
    i %= album.length;
    while ( album[i].disabled ) {
        i--;
        i %= album.length;
    }
    return i;
}
```

The output works as long it is above 0

```
TypeError: album[i] is undefined
undefined = "0"   
while ( album[i].disabled )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following logic is pretty simple. The trick is to just keep iterating until you find one that is not disabled, using modulus (`%`) to perform the loop-around when you hit the end.

```
function getNext() {
    var i = this.currPhotoId + 1;
    i %= this.album.length;
    while ( this.album[i].disabled ) {
        i++;
        i %= this.album.length;
    }
    return this.album[i];
}

function getPrev() {
    var i = this.currPhotoId - 1;
    i %= this.album.length;
    while ( this.album[i].disabled ) {
        i--;
        i %= this.album.length;
    }
    return this.album[i];
}
```

Just make sure there's at least one that *is* enabled or this will loop infinitely. :)

Comment: Thanks, i managed to tweak it a little bit so it gives me the output i wanted :D You're my hero!

Comment: You can add the functions to any instance of your album to support multiple albums: e.g. `album.getNext = getNext`. If you want it to be a totally isolated function you will need to pass in the current index and a reference to the album to iterate or else it will have no way of determining if the next/previous one is disabled or not. In that case add e.g. an `album` parameter and change each instance of `this.album` in the body to `album`, and same for `currPhotoId`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeImage(element, event){
    var albumHolder = document.getElementById('album');
    albumHolder.removeChild(element);
    event.preventDefault();
    currPhotoId = element.id.split("_");

    // This should be a bit simpler
    album[currPhotoId].disabled = true;
    console.log(album);
}
```

then...

```
function disabledCheck(currentID, direction)
if(album[currentID].disabled){
    // search for next one which isn't disabled in next or previous direction
}else{
    return currentID
}
```

if you want to skip this element and search for the next no-disabled one

```
function disabledCheck(currentID, direction)
for(var i = 0; i < (album.length - currentID))
{
    if(album[currentID].disabled){
        // search for next one which isn't disabled in next or previous direction
        continue;
    }else{
        return currentID
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: sorry its a bit quick, I dont know if you want me to talk you through it? You could swap out the continue for an if / else statement, but that in itself should work

Comment: Yea, i could use some extra help with that one. It also has to start on the currentID right?

Comment: My bad I thought u wanted to iterate. i'll have another look. I think u might be overcomplicating your first function though

Comment: Well, all i need is a function which checks if the next or previous ID is disabled if that is the cause then he should be checking which is next in line but not disabled. For example id 2 is the current id 3 is disabled so the function returns 4 and if 4 is also disabled it returns 5

Comment: Yes but in the part about '// search for next one which isn't disabled in next or previous direction' i need the last loop which checks for the next in line, not disabled

Comment: lol I think i'm tired tonight. Yeah you just loop like the first function I wrote. This should help but u miht need to tweak it

Comment: Thanks tho for your help! I really appreciate it! ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8552/discussion-between-delano-de-rooij-and-outrunthewolf)